# SockJS over stomp using angular2 and spring boot

Tags: angular, spring-boot, websocket, sockjs

I want to implement a websocket inside my projet to do something as notifications

this is my configuration web socket in my projet spring boot

```
 @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/hello").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
    }
```

and in my controller I have this method :

```
@MessageMapping("/hello")
    @SendTo("/topic/templatesWS")
    public void TemplatesWebSocket() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("calling juste");
    }
```

and in my client side in my page index.html I added this

```
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/sockjs/1/sockjs.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/stomp.js/2.3.3/stomp.js"></script>
```

and in my component angular2 I'm using this

```
declare let SockJS;
        declare let Stomp;


        var socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:8080/hello');
        socket.ono
        var stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
            stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
            console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
            stompClient.subscribe('http://localhost:8080/template/topic/templatesWS', function(greeting) {
                console.log("from from", greeting);
            });
        }, function (err) {
            console.log('err', err);
        });
```

How can I call the method TemplatesWebSocket()

[image]

Comment: I think the subscribe() parameter should be simply '/topic/templatesWS'

Comment: How send data to server Or get and object after an event ?

Comment: I resolve this error I have some configuration websocket security that prevent connection

but the line code stompClient.subscribe not call the method from controller 
TemplatesWebSocket() how can I call it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this example I just uploaded:
https://github.com/mtrojahn/spring-boot-websocket

I think what you meant is send a command to the server and get a response, right? The example above covers both the response to a command sent by the client and also periodic messages sent to the clients.

You are probably looking for something like this:

```
stompClient.client.send("/app/somecommand", {}, "");
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: the send method it works fine but stompClient.subscribe not working 
why we use the subscribe method ?? 
when we subscribe in a method with scheduled is for getting for example data every 20 secondes but in case with MessageMapping if you can explain that to me thanks (I updat the question I add the picture of subscribe method error)

Comment: Websockets is about subscribing to a service and wait for data. The server pushes (broadcast) data to all subscribed clients. The 20s example shows that happening, every 20s your client will receive a message.

Your problem with the subscribe method being undefined sounds like a problem with the order the scripts are being loaded by the browser.